# Errors compiling source code for Aseprite on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: 22.04

Here is the error code I get when I try to compile the source code for Aseprite on Ubuntu Linux 22.04:

```
cran@cran-MacBookPro:~/aseprite$ mkdir build
cran@cran-MacBookPro:~/aseprite$ cd build
cran@cran-MacBookPro:~/aseprite/build$ cmake -G Ninja -DLAF_BACKEND=skia
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Error: The source directory "/home/cran/aseprite/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Is there anyway I can fix this error and get the application running? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Likely the `CMakeLists.txt` file is in the build directory's parent (`..`), so you need to run `cmake -G Ninja -DLAF_BACKEND=skia ..`